# Align children of stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf

How can the children of the Stack panel be aligned independently? I have an image which is to be aligned to right and a *Label* which is to be aligned to left. The orientation property of StackPanel is set to "Horizontal".

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label x:Name="titleLb" Content="Label 1" />
            <Image Height="37" Name="image1" Width="129" Source="/GUITest;component/Images/logo.png"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

```
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="123" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="345" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Tried that. That doesn't give the required effect. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/GFkT7.png